# 32GB Flash Voyager doesn't work on new PC with USB 3.0

Tags: windows-7, drivers, usb-flash-drive, usb-3

**I have recently built a new PC and my pendrive is not working correctly.**

When I plug it into the USB port (I have only USB 3.0 ports), Windows recognizes it and lists it in Explorer, as usual.

I open it, and try to paste some files on the pendrive.

The files begin to copy but after a short moment (say 10s), the transfer stops, and after another 5s Windows says that the drive is unavailable etc.

It disapears from Explorer too (the icon is half-transparent).

After removing and pluging the pendrive in again it is visible, until a write attempt.

---

My setup:

- **Pendrive:**  Corsair Flash Voyager GT 32GB (used it for ca. 1 year now)
- **Mainboard:** Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD3H (with newest BIOS)
- **OS:** Windows 7 Pro, 64bit

I've updated all the drivers (Intel) and BIOS, and I still can't use the pendrive.

I **can** use other peripherials though (USB mice, keyboard), **other pendrives** too! The not-working pendrive works on other PCs.

---

Update:

I manager to narrow down the problem: it's the Intel USB 3.0 driver - `Intel® USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver`

When I uninstalled it, the pendrive works like a charm, but it's not the USB 3.0 speed i'd expect. When I installed the newest Intel drivers (Feb 2014), the issue returned and the pendrive is useless.

Perhaps this small input can help somebody help me... What can I do?

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try the pendrive on all ports? Do other USB 3.0 pendrives work?

Comment: @and31415 Other pendrives work on all ports. This pendrive doesn't work on any :-(

Comment: And yet it you use it on another computer, and copy some files over, the whole operation completes successfully. Is that right?

Comment: @and31415 Yes. I used it on my old PC too, my TV media player... I believe it's a problem with driver.. some driver, but I don't know which.. I have a second Corsair 16GB (also USB 3.0) and it works just fine.. so I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Is there anything relevant in Event Log?

Answer (score 0):

try formatting, it with NTFS and see if the problem is gone, otherwise try once more formatting it with FAT32 system.

Comment: After formatting to NTFS I was able to copy a few files, but then the problem returned. After formatting to FAT32 again, I couldn't copy a single file. All formats were *quick*, will try a full one

Comment: edit: I was not able to perform a full format, because the drive disconnected, just as during copying.....

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've localized the problem to the driver, there can be only a few culprits:

1. The driver proper

   - it may incorrectly handle some exchange patterns that only your pendrive uses and none other of your peripherals
2. The USB controller at your motherboard (it's typically integrated into the southbridge)

   - other peripherals you listed likely don't use such high speeds, and when the controller works in USB 2.0 mode, speeds are likewise much lower
3. The pendrive

   - a bug/defect (incl. a consequence of wear) that other MBs you have have workarounds for but not this one

(Cables are out of question - you said it doesn't work in any of the ports. I assume there are at least a few directly on the motherboard.)

I'd call 2) - a defect in the particular MB - the most likely cause.

To rule out:

- 1) - test it with another fully functional driver (e.g. boot from a Linux LiveCD). Make sure the driver really is fully functional - i.e. that it makes the controller work at 3.0 speeds and fully supports the southbridge. Ideally, this should be the driver supplied by the MB's vendor - if it supplies them for anything other than Windows (other Windows versions are too close, drivers for them are likely to have the same bug. Of course, it won't hurt to try - maybe they don't!).
- 2) - test with another MB of the same model, or at least with the same chipset and driver (or a different driver but the same PCI IDs - provided you also do 1) to clean the driver from suspicion).
- 3) - test with another pendrive that's likely to act in the same exact manner - the same model or a larger model of the same model line. Alternatively, another USB device that will load MB's USB circuitry to the max may do.

You may be able to have a service center or the vendor you bought from do 2) for you.